# How to set min and max width in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have input field which will have initial width of col-md-2 and based on user input length it should be increased maximum to col-md-4. How can I do it?

```
<div class="section row">
 <div class="col-md-2 " id="">
     <div class="section"></div>
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-4" id="">
     <div class="section"></div>
 </div>
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Would you be ok with using some JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: try this  #id-of-div { width:100%; }

Comment: I'd recommend just adding the CSS yourself, as it's not that complicated. Like this: width: auto; min-width: 20%; max-width: 33%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try https://jsfiddle.net/6penznju/3/

```
function changeColumn() {   document.getElementById("change").className = "col-md-4";
```

Comment: can't we make it automatic without javascript?

Answer (score -1):

Well,

try to understunding the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

In your case I'll try, from:

```
col-md-2 col-md-4
```

to

```
col-md-2 col-lg-1
```

Comment: None of the suggestions are working. Please see my edit. I have tagsinput for one  input field inside a bootstrap div of section row, based on number of tags entered by the user, I want to increase the width up to some extent by moving adjacent columns as well